# Existential subquery and OR in WHERE clause cause UnknownError

Tags: neo4j, cypher

An `UnknownError` occurs when I use `EXISTS {...}` in conjunction with `OR` in a `WHERE` clause. Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Create sample nodes

```
CREATE (a:A { uuid:'uuid1', foo:true })-[:KNOWS]->(b:B { uuid:'uuid2' })
```

Sample query

```
MATCH (a:A { uuid:'uuid1' }),
(b:B { uuid:'uuid2' })
WHERE a.foo = TRUE
OR EXISTS {
  MATCH (a)-[:KNOWS]->(b)
}
RETURN a
```

Error

```
Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError
There should be at least one pattern expression
```

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using?

Comment: I'm running 4.0.1 Enterprise

Comment: Okay, there is something going on here. Although MATCH should be before the pattern in the brackets, I'm still getting the same error. There may be a bug here related to combining an existential subquery with further predicates in the same WHERE clause. I'll check with some people on this.

Comment: I added the MATCH. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @InverseFalcon indicates, this does seem like a bug (or at least an undocumented [existential subquery](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/clauses/where/#existential-subquery-simple-case) limitation).

As a workaround, since your subquery has no `WHERE` clause, you can just use the [EXISTS](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/functions/predicate/#functions-exists) function:

```
MATCH (a:A {uuid: 'uuid1'}), (b:B {uuid: 'uuid2'})
WHERE a.foo OR EXISTS((a)-[:KNOWS]->(b))
RETURN a
```

Comment: I posted a simplified query in my question. My actual query unfortunately does include a `WHERE` clause. Should I report the bug or put in a feature request?

Comment: I would consider this a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This was indeed a bug/oversight in Neo4j's existential subquery implementation. I have now implemented a fix [Solve bug with existential subqueries and OR](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/commit/dc2065943bdfa236ccc87bdb5e051cce4f8bf523) which will be included in a upcoming 4.0 release.